# Calculating correct area for polygons with geopandas

Tags: python, area, geopandas

I recently tried to calculate country sizes with geopandas and the included world file; and I am not capable to calculate the correct size for the chosen countries. Maybe someone can give me a hint where I made a mistake?

Tried various shapefiles (and the included world file shipped with geopandas); all of the afaik in epsg:4326

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cnames = ['Austria','Sweden','Kenya']
epsgs = ['3857','3395']

for c in cnames:
    carea = world[world['name'] == c]
    for e in epsgs:
        carea = carea.to_crs(epsg=e)
        area = int(pd.to_numeric(carea['geometry'].area)/10**6)
        print(area)
```

Expected results are:

- Austria: 83,879 km²
- Sweden: 450,295 km²
- Kenya:  580,367 km²

Actual results I get:

- Austria: 187163
- Austria: 186592
- Sweden: 2190160
- Sweden: 2187138
- Kenya: 595731
- Kenya: 591749

So Kenya is quite close (also to the equator)? Is the reprojection not right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get correct area, you must use 'equal-area' projection. The one that works well with your code is `epsg 6933`. It is cylindrical equal-area projection.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot.

In this question they talk about 3395 being an equal area crs:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218450/getting-polygon-areas-using-geopandas/218453

one of the reasons I was not on the right path :)